# Overly long questions and how to deal with them

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I'm wondering whether there is a good method of dealing with expanded questions that start with the auxiliary verb "to be"? Or perhaps there's something wrong with my questions?

> 1) Wait, so is the guy who's currently hiding behind the table, all clad in white and green, with an ugly scar going through half of his face, your father?
>
> 2) Were people whose entire wealth consisted of a small cottage, two cows and a couple of hens, considered rich in the 10th century?
>
> 3) Have you, as a child of rich parents, always spoiled and taken care of, ever been sad?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking -- what do you mean by "dealing with" these questions?

Comment: So is the guy (big long set of adjective phrases) your father? -> There's a guy (big long set of adjective phrases); is he your father?    Is that what you want?

Comment: I mean, do they not feel like a mouthful to you?

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking is: are they still correct and idiomatic, although so expanded and complex?

Comment: @BebopB. they're certainly "a mouthful" but not especially long.  See this from "Stuart Little", a children's novel by E.B. White:

Comment: “In the loveliest town of all, where the houses were white and high and the elms trees were green and higher than the houses, where the front yards were wide and pleasant and the back yards were bushy and worth finding out about, where the streets sloped down to the stream and the stream flowed quietly under the bridge, where the lawns ended in orchards and the orchards ended in fields and the fields ended in pastures and the pastures climbed the hill and disappeared over the top toward the wonderful wide sky, in this loveliest of all towns Stuart stopped to get a drink of sarsaparilla.”

Comment: @BebopB. I think other languages (like German) are even more notorious for this kind of thing.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes if a question is getting really long with adjectives, we break it up in a way that's maybe not formally grammatically correct, but makes it a lot easier to understand.  "Wait, so that guy - that guy with the big nose and the green suit, the one who came in about ten minutes ago - that guy's your father?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with long questions like your examples. It is a matter of style.

That said, *if* you feel that such a sentence is a problem that you want to deal with, the easy solution is to move your description so that it does not interrupt the question -- give the question up front, then provide detail. Here are three example solutions:

> 1) **Is your father that guy** who's currently hiding behind the table, all clad in white and green, with an ugly scar going through half of his face?
>
> 2) **Were people considered rich** in the 10th century if their entire wealth consisted of a small cottage, two cows and a couple of hens?
>
> 3) **Have you ever been sad**, ( given that / even though ) you are a child of rich parents, always taken care of and spoiled?